# How to stop requesting google geocoding api when website is being crawled

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I am using Google Geocoding API, Website is not having much traffic as of now but it is exceeding the daily limit of 2500 request per day.
I checked and found that it is exceeding the daily limit because the website is being crawled by various websites/ search engine, including crawling by Google.

Is there any way to stop the requests generated to Google API when website is being crawled? OR is there any way through which we can stop executing the Code, if the website is being crawled by some websites, including Google?

Comment: It's useful to share what you've already tried and hasn't worked when posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, my code is like this:

```
def geocoding(address):
    print(address)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    g=geocoder.google(address)
    return g.latlng

def main():
    cases()
    for count in range(len(addresses)):
        code= geocoding(addresses[count])
        print code
        try:
            latitude.append(code[0])
             longitude.append(code[1])
        except:
            latitude.append("")
            longitude.append("")           
        writeExcel()
```

And as you can see, I did a loop
addresses, latitute and longituitde are arrays and write excels puts the arrays into excel

If you create a check, you can stop the loop with a break:

```
def main():
    cases()
    for count in range(len(addresses)):
        code= geocoding(addresses[count])
        if code[0]=="":
           break
        print code
        try:
            latitude.append(code[0])
            longitude.append(code[1])
        except:
            latitude.append("")
            longitude.append("")           
        writeExcel()
```